# Android: convertir Bitmap a File

Tags: android

Tengo un problema al convertir un **Bitmap** el cual es una imagen, a **File**. Espero y me puedan ayudar.

---

Para convertir a File mi imagen lo que hice fue lo siguiente

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
nameImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto

```
private static void convertBitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {
    File filesDir = getAppContext().getFilesDir();
    File imageFile = new File(filesDir, name + ".jpg");

    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error writing bitmap", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola sioesi tengo una duda, persistImage tiene como parametro un String pero no como lo tendria que hacer porque unicamente yo tengo el Bitmap

Comment: el string es el nombre de la imagen, el cual quieras

Comment: mmmm lo que pasa es lo siguiente, tengo el Bitmap para despues convertirlo a File y obtener el archivo para posteriormente eliminarla del servidor

Comment: Por eso le agrego el nombre, asi sabes que archivo eliminar

Comment: Pero como yo le asigno el nombre si unicamente tengo el Bitmap, de que forma

Comment: El nombre que tu quieras, un string cualquiera

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50209/discussion-between-javier-fr-and-sioesi).

Comment: @Javierfr  anda al chat